# problem with sockets in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, object, serializable

I have the following thread which accepts for incoming connections at a specific port:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket clientSocket;
    int serverPort = 6500;
    private String serverIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    DataInputStream is;
    ObjectOutputStream os=null;
    Coordinate coord;

    protected BlockingQueue queue = null;

    public ClientThread(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetSocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress(
                    serverIpAddress, serverPort);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.bind(serverAddr);
            System.out.println("s-a creat");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to host");
        }

        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("S-a conectat clientul de monitorizare!");

            os=new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            try{
                while(true){
                    coord=(Coordinate)queue.take();
                    System.out.println(coord.getLat()+coord.getLon()+coord.getwId());
                    os.writeObject(coord);
                    os.flush();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
                os.close();
            }catch(Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The object I'm trying to send is an instance of the following class:

```
public class Coordinate implements Serializable{
    private final int lon;
    private final int lat;
    private final int workerId;

    public Coordinate(int lat, int lon, int workerId) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.workerId=workerId;
    }

    public int getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public int getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public int getwId() {
        return workerId;
    }
}
```

---

But when I start the thread and I accept for connection I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at servers.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

Anyone anyidea of what is wrong?

---

This error  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort appears when one of the socket end crashes....in my case was the end that connected to ClientThread() and when I was trying to write in the buffer the error appeared.

Comment: Which line is line 55 of ClientThread.java?

Comment: os.writeObject(coord); this one,but don't bother with it cause my problem is a different one...I have a Geocoder on the other side of the socket that makes my connection crash...I'll try to fix it and if it doesn't work I'll post another question.Thx

Answer (score 1):

You did not put the client side code and it is hard to understand what can client to do, but I see one part of code where can be problem. It is

```
 while(true){
                    coord=(Coordinate)queue.take();
                    System.out.println(coord.getLat()+coord.getLon()+coord.getwId());
                    os.writeObject(coord);
                    os.flush();
                }
```

What is `java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error` meaning? It means that connection was closed BUT you tried to write some data to socket. But I can be wrong.

Comment: No u are noot wrong...the connection was closed from the other side;).....u are good at this;)

Comment: It will be better to analyze all code, not just a one side, please in future post all scope of code :) Cheers :)